# Facebook Graph API v2.2 me/friends only returns no. of users

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Okay firstly, i have visited all related questions on StackOverflow and i could not find my answer. So please do not mark this as a duplicate of a similar question.

I am using the latest Graph APIs v2.2 to get list of FB friends who are using my app.

Request Android Code-

```
    Session activesession=Session.getActiveSession();
    if(activesession!=null){
        new Request(
                activesession,
                "/v2.2/me/friends",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String strresponse=response.getRawResponse();
                        JSONObject jsonresponse=null;
                        try {
                            jsonresponse = new JSONObject(strresponse);                             
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            ).executeAsync();           
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Session is NULL");
    }
}
```

Response-
{
   "data": [

],
   "summary": {
      "total_count": 199
   }
}

I know for sure that i have one friend on my FB friends list who has downloaded the same app & is logged in to it via FB.

Also i tried something similar using FB Graph explorer tool & it gave me the same response-

I am expecting at least one user detail in the data array. Not sure what i am missing here.

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Did both you and the friend grant `user_friends` permission?

Comment: You mean authorizing the app to get friends? Yes we both did that when logging in to the app.

Comment: Currently my App details are not available on FB. I am wondering if this may be causing the issue?

Comment: And I’m wondering what that is even supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

try this me/taggable_friend instend of me/friend hope it will works

Session activesession=Session.getActiveSession();
    if(activesession!=null){
        new Request(
                activesession,
                "/v2.2/me/taggable_friend",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String strresponse=response.getRawResponse();
                        JSONObject jsonresponse=null;
                        try {
                            jsonresponse = new JSONObject(strresponse);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            ).executeAsync();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Session is NULL");
    }
}

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try like this for v2.2 in facebook

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("fields", "name,picture,id");

new Request(session, "/me/friends", bundle,  HttpMethod.GET, new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        System.out.println("response=============="+response);
    }
}).executeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void getFriends() {
    Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (activeSession.getState().isOpened()) {
        new Request(
                activeSession,
                "/me/friends",
                null,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                        GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                        if (graphObject != null) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                                JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

                                for (i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                                    final String name = data.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                                    final String id = data.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        ).executeAsync();
    }
}
```